# React-Native: Undefined is not an object ONLY when trying to get the value outside of an if/switch statement

Tags: reactjs, switch-statement, undefined

```
switch (Object.keys(api.container1.Monday)) {
    case undefined: console.log("undefined!!!");
    default: return console.log(Object.keys(api.container1.Monday));
}
```

The switch case ignores the undefined, as it not undefined and continues to the default. after reaching default, I get the error

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'api.container1.Monday')
```

Comment: `Object.keys(api.container1.Monday)` will return you an Array.

Comment: Just a heads up. You probably want a `break` or `return` after the first case. Otherwise, it will continue to default.